# Check if dataframe has a zero element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, what is the quickest way to check if at least one element is 0? Imagine the data is :

```
Name   Asset  Revenue
A       10     20
B       0      21
```

I need to return true because at least one element is 0. One element across the dataframe, not one element per row/column

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe using `any` twice

```
df.eq(0).any().any()
Out[173]: True
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do in this way:

```
 0 in df.values
```

Comment: I believe this would be the fastest. Great answer +1.

Comment: Be careful. This doesn't work for floats with 0 value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df.isin([0]).any().any()
```